# Java: use NIO with System.in

Tags: java, nio, system.in

Is it possible to use NIO with System.in?

I would like to somehow treat 'stdin' as a selectable channel.  Has anyone found a way to do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

duplicate:

[How to get SelectableChannel from an InputStream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/765981/how-to-get-selectablechannel-from-an-inputstream)

hmmm... on second thought, for stdin there may be a solution. I found this reference:

http://www.javafaq.nu/java-example-code-346.html

and in particular:

[SystemInPipe.java](http://www.javafaq.nu/java-example-code-347.html) (class which encapsulates stdin as a selectable channel)

Comment: I appreciate what that guy is trying to do in SystemInPipe, but its still not much better than spawning a daemon thread to poll it.  Problem is you can't interrupt that thread (ever).

Comment: This is a classic example of why answers that are primarily links are strongly discouraged on StackOverflow.  The link to `javafaq.nu` is dead, so the answer is worthless.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about a `SelectableChannel`, but you can convert an `InputStream` to a `ReadableByteChannel` with

```
using java.nio.channels.Channels;

...

ReadableByteChannel in = Channels.newChannel(System.in);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a [`Pipe`](http://java.nio.channels.Pipe) and a custom thread to read from standard input and write to the pipe.

Once you have the `Pipe` you can then get the input channel.