# Is there epoll equivalent in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, epoll

Is there an equivalent of Linux epoll in Java?

epoll allows a thread to react to a number of heterogenous events.  For instance, I can have a thread that reacts to either a socket event or an input from the console.  In C++ I can implement this by registering stdio and the socket with epoll.  My thread will be triggered by an event from either if these.

Is there a similar facility in Java?  I looked at the nio package, it allows me to register a number of sockets with a selector.  But there does not seem to be away to register the console / standard io with a selector.  Am I not seeing something?  Is there another way to do this?

On the "why": I want to write a program that communicates via sockets, and i want to drive this program by entering commands from console.  I know how this can be done by separating console input and the communications to different threads, but i am curious whether there is a way to do this in a single thread.

Thanks.
df

Comment: Can you take a step back and edit your post to explain _why_ you want to do this?

Comment: I guess standard 'console input' would probably be `System.in` (although you should inject the reference, not hard-code the use).  However, it doesn't look like it generates events (ie - there's no `register()` or similar method), so I don't think there's default behaviour like you want.  You'd have to write (or find) something to provide this behaviour.

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915262/java-use-nio-with-system-in and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/765981/how-to-get-selectablechannel-from-an-inputstream

Answer (score 30):

Enhancements in Java SE 6

`java.nio`

A new `java.nio.channels.SelectorProvider` implementation that is based on the Linux epoll event notification facility is included. The epoll facility is available in the Linux 2.6, and newer, kernels. The new epoll-based SelectorProvider implementation is more scalable than the traditional poll-based SelectorProvider implementation when there are thousands of SelectableChannels registered with a Selector. The new SelectorProvider implementation will be used by default when the 2.6 kernel is detected. The poll-based SelectorProvider will be used when a pre-2.6 kernel is detected.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/io/enhancements.html

Comment: Is this portable to non-linux Java implementations?  Also, can you get a `SelectorProvider` on the console?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, the `nio` package allows the use of `Selector`s which supply the functionality equivalent of `poll()`/`select()` and actually one of the implementations uses `epoll` as the backend (this is selected via `java.nio.channels.spi.SelectorProvider` Java property). Selectors are usually used with network sockets, but if you look through the different `Channel` implementations in the docs, I think it's likely you will be able to use this mechanism with standard input as well (there are helper classes which allow moving between old `Stream`-based APIs and the `nio` APIs to some degree).

Comment: You can't. You can't register any channel with a `Selector` that isn't a `SelectableChannel`, and the only `SelectableChannels` are the socket channels and the pipe channels.